# Angular & Ionic, $http not working in real device Android

Tags: angularjs, ajax, web-services, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic application and using `$http` for get the data from web service. I have tested and its working on browser perfectly but i don't know why its not working on my android mobile, it just keep processing and after 3 to 5 mins it shows:

```
ionic.bundle.js:25000 POST http://xyz-domain.com/api/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Even i have installed `cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin but still getting same.

My Code:

```
var ApiURL = 'http://xyz-domain.com/api/';
$http({

    url: ApiURL,
    method: 'POST',
    data: 'action=activate&app_secret=123456',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}).then(function(res){
    alert(res);
});
```

Can any one please tell me how i can solve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might be the case that your white list plugin and android platform version are not compatible.Happened to me also.Updating the platform and the plugin resolved the issue.Also can you alert the data, status, headers, config that are returned by the service.

Comment: yes, i think there is problem in my server..because i just debug using google chrome and its showing api call but not responding, that means $http still working but not getting response.

Comment: You can use following command to install the plugin. To do that in command prompt go to your project folder and execute following command.

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist

More info please refer this URL. This gives permission to android for populating data on real device.